# How to deserialize and set that data to textfield in javafx?

Tags: javafx-8

I have been working on a class project using javafx and I have to serialize all the data and load all the data to project when the project is launched. I was able to serialize the data from the textfield but unable to load the serialized data to the textfield. 
Here is my serialization code:

```
public class Controller {
    Employee nameFile = new Employee();
    @FXML
    private TextField firstNameField;
    @FXML
    private TextField lastNameField;
public void getinfo() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        String filename = "file.abc";
        nameFile.setFirstNameField(firstNameField.getText());
        nameFile.setLastNameField(lastNameField.getText());

        // Serialization
        try
        {

            //Saving of object in a file
            File employeeName = new File("file.abc");
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(employeeName);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);

            out.writeObject(nameFile);
            out.close();
            file.close();

            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Information Saved");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Your Information has been saved!");
            alert.showAndWait();

        }

        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException is caught");
        }
    }

    public void setDataField() {

        try {
            // Reading the object from a file

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("file.abc");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(file);

            // Method for deserialization of object
            nameFile = (Employee) in.readObject();
           /*How to I pull that data to the textfield firstnamefield and     lastnamefield this method is invoked */
            in.close();
            file.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException is caught");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IOException is caught");

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(file);

// Method for deserialization of object
nameFile = (Employee) in.readObject();

// *** Here we set data back to text fields ***
firstNameField.setText(nameFile.getFirstNameField());
lastNameField.setText(nameFile.getLastNameField());
```